# WPF, why adding PropertyChanged to List<> does not take into effect?

Tags: wpf, list, propertychanged

why PropertyChangedEvent can be add to a String property, but cannot be add to a List<> property?

the xaml likes this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Height="300"/>
    <Button Click="Button_Click">Change</Button>
</StackPanel>
```

and the xaml.cs like this:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    //public ObservableCollection<String> Items { get; set; } = new ObservableCollection<String>(); // ok
    public List<String> Items  // no effect
    {
        get { return _items; }
        set
        {
            _items = value;
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Items"));
        }
    }
    private List<String> _items = new List<string>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Items.Add("aaa");
        Items.Add("bbb");
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            Items.Add(i.ToString());
     }
}
```

Comment: You made a typical misunderstanding on `PropertyChanged` of collections. In this case, you need to use `ObservableCollection` which implements `CollectionChanged` to nofity the change of items inside the collection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue can be fixed in multiple ways,

1. Create another List on Button Click, sample code given below
2. Use Observable Collection

   Change

   ```
       private RelayCommand _buttonClick;
        public RelayCommand ButtonClick => _buttonClick ?? new RelayCommand(onButtonClick, canButtonClick);

    private bool canButtonClick(object obj)
    {
        return true;
    }

    private void onButtonClick(object obj)
    {
        List<String> tempItems = new List<string>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            tempItems.Add(i.ToString());
        Items = tempItems;
    }
   ```

Comment: yes, i see. in my old code,  although elements of Items changed, Items itself not change, and there's no PropertyChangedEvent. in your new code, Items itself changes, so PropertyChangedEvent occurs.  thank you for your reply!

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because you're only notifying when the entire List is set, not when items are added or removed within the list.

Use an `ObservableCollection<string>` instead of `List<string>`:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private ObservableCollection<string> _Items = new ObservableCollection<string>();
    public ObservableCollection<string> Items
    {
        get { return _Items; }
        set
        {
            _Items = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Items));
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
        Items.Add("aaa");
        Items.Add("bbb");
    }

    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Items.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            Items.Add(i.ToString());
     }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I see. thank you for your reply.